# Azure Mobile Service, Monogame, Windows Phone 8 and resuming a tombstoned app

Tags: azure, windows-phone-8, azure-mobile-services, monogame, tombstoning

I have an app that requires immense amount of resources relative to the phone capabilities. It would appear that when I press the windows phone, the app get instantly tombstoned as resuming it doesn't provide the same result anymore. As far as I can tell, Monogame loads the resources that were loaded with Content.Load, but all my private render targets, etc. appear to be gone.

Bigger problem, however, is that there are open ended Azure Mobile Service requests and when resuming, all kinda stuff fails to missed callbacks etc.

All-in-all, I would be fine with just restarting the app on resuming, but I haven't found a smart way to do this. Is there a reasonable way to just call some sort of restart method on app resume? Furthermore, is there a way to affect the time after which the app goes tombstoned after windows button is pressed, or is this something I just have to live with?

Comment: For the mobile services calls that are missing callbacks can you provide a snippet code of how you are calling them?

I believe on the resume, the http operations in progress will return an exception, and you should be able to catch that exception where you are making the calls to your mobile service.

Comment: Ohh, my bad. The MobileServiceExceptions I am able to nicely catch. I think the bigger problem was the WCF calls as they actually use a proper EAP calls unlike WinRT.

Comment: Furthermore, I tried creating an empty MonoGame project and resuming that and I just get a directx exception, so I guess there are more problems here than just the requests. :) But the requests are currently breaking it so.